# Restart a Airflow TASK

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have an Airflow job with 77 (11*7) Task. When any one Task fails, I do not want the DAG to FAIL. Instead, I want to auto restart the failed Task again (twice) and then even if it fails, I need the DAG to fail. Is is possible to auto restart the Task?
Task failure happens when i copy a file from SFTP to S3. The file size is 4GB. Due to some timeout error (in AWS), this failure happens.
My ASK: Can anyone please help me to figure out on How to restart a Task automatically in case of failure. Also how to restart a DAG automatically in case of failure. This restart should happen twice and then FAIL the TASK/DAG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to provide `retries` arguments which is the number of retries that should be performed before failing the task, by default it's equal to the setting `core.default_task_retries` if it's provided or 0 if not. (you can provide it to the dag default args if you want to set it for all the dag tasks)

You can also decide how long Airflow has to wait before retry the task by setting `retry_delay`, and if you want an exponential wait time, you can set `retry_exponential_backoff` to `True`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The Task that has SFTPtoS3Operator is failing and in that operator we do not have any `retries` argument. Can you please help me on where to add this argument?

Comment: This argument exists in the BaseOperator and all the operators because they extend it, just provide it to your tasks

Comment: `@dag(dag_id=edw_dag_id, start_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 12, 0, 00),
schedule_interval = '0 9 * * *',
catchup=False,
params = {"date_str": date_str_val})
def tasks_sftp():
DAT101_LOAD_DAT_BATCH_START = PythonOperator(
task_id="DAT101",
python_callable=edw_common.call_procedure,
provide_context=True,
params={
'query_name' : 'DAT101_LOAD_DAT_BATCH_START_SQL'
}
)
sftp_to_s3_data = SFTPToS3Operator(
task_id = "DAT201",
sftp_conn_id = _sftp_conn_id,
sftp_path = path_given,
s3_bucket = S3_BUCKET,
s3_key = Key_given
)`
Where to add `retries` in `SFTPToS3Operator`??

Comment: `sftp_to_s3_data = SFTPToS3Operator( task_id = "DAT201", sftp_conn_id = _sftp_conn_id, sftp_path = path_given, s3_bucket = S3_BUCKET, s3_key = Key_given, retries=2)`, same for the other operators.

Comment: It worked. I gave the `retries` & `retry_delay` and this worked as expected. I tried to give `retry` and that failed. So I got confused. I am yet to check in the main job that deals with 4GB file. But as of now, this option is working.